# Issue with Win32 package in Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am on [LTS 8.15](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.15). I am starting a basic, default, library for which I will need to use the [win32 package](https://www.stackage.org/nightly-2017-05-28/package/Win32-2.3.1.1).

Using these dependencies in the cabal file :

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                       , win32
```

I get the following error message :

```
While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for w32test-0.1.0.0:
    win32 must match -any, but the stack configuration has no specified version

Plan construction failed.
```

I tried to force a package version :

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                       , win32 == 2.3.1.1
```

but I got the same error message again :

```
While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for w32test-0.1.0.0:
    win32 must match ==2.3.1.1, but the stack configuration has no specified version

Plan construction failed.
```

In case it matters for the answer, here is my minimalistic stack.yaml file :

```
resolver: lts-8.15
packages:
- '.'
extra-deps: []
flags: {}
extra-package-dbs: []
```

**My question** : I do not understand what's going wrong, can anyone suggest a way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a case sensitivity issue to me, can you try adding it as Win32.

Comment: It worked! Silly me, I never noticed that package names were case sensitive. Thank you.

Comment: But, thinking about it, would an error message saying that Stack cannot find the misspelled package name be more useful for troubleshooting?

Comment: I thought something like that existed, but it clearly didn't work here. Maybe you'd be interested in trying out a PR for the feature?